# Message ID in a POP3 protocol

Tags: pop3

my task is to retrieve a set of messages from GMail via POP3 (no IMAP).
I can do RETR MSG #, and it is prohibited to delete.

Fetchmail and procmail are constantly trying to download a same set of new, unread messages (this part goes to ServerFault). Is there a header specially designed to distinguish previously read messages? Or I should do checksum of message body/subject/date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POP3 protocol doesn't support a read/seen sort of flag.  Some servers support a non-standard header like `X-Seen` which acts like a read flag, you'll have to use the `TOP` to get a message's headers and see if it's been set (well more to determine if it's even there).

It's supposed to be up to the client to cover read flags in POP3, but the good news is you don't need to do a checksum, just use the `UIDL` which will give you a list of non-changing, unique IDs for the messages in the inbox, or if called with a message # will give you the unique ID for the message in that position in the mailbox (since you can't guarantee message position in the mailbox if other client's are accessing and may be deleting).

Comment: I have a related problem, which is to be able to work with messages in a mailbox that other clients are accessing.  How can a client delete a message safely when the only identifier is the message number, and this can change without warning?  In other words, if you want to delete message #1, but some other client deletes that message, you'd actually be deleting message #2, and you'd have no idea.  What is the right way to handle this?

Comment: You'd want to be getting the `UIDL` at display time (which can be looked up by message #) and delete by that instead of `message #`.  You could try and cross reference `message #` to `UIDL` at delete time, but it's subject to the same flaw.  If `UIDL` isn't an option, you'll need to compare or headers (which covers supposedly-unique message-id, send/received dates, title etc) and message size to reduce doubt.

Answer (score -1):

Try to control messages with message-id

```
Message message ;
....
String messageId = message.getHeader("message-id")[0];
```